# Schengen visa for Spain

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, spain

Can I apply for Schengen visa while staying in US but travel plans are from india to Europe and back to India? And do I need to confirm the tickets from US to India

Comment: Whether you have to confirm your US > India air ticket (and how and when to do it), will be stated by your air carrier. Go to the carrier's web page to find out. And the mechanics of applying for a Schengen visa — including where you can be when you apply, and where the application must be filed — will depend on your citizenship and which country you apply to, as different countries have different policies and procedures for applicants of differing nationalities.

Answer (score 2):

For Schengen visa, you should apply *from* your country of residence, *at* the embassy or consulate for your place of residence. Exceptions are possible, but claiming an exception means you must argue that you are a hardship case. Better do it right.

The fact that you would arrive and leave through a third country is no problem. You wrote that you are **staying** in the US. Are you a citizen or permanent resident? If so, you should apply from the US. Explain the travel plans and where you will go after visiting the Schengen area.

Comment: I am not a permanent resident in US. I’m working on work visa here but I am planning to apply schengen visa from US. My travel plans would be from India only and I’m planning to visit Spain and France.

Comment: In that case, you would have to explain why you cannot apply from your place of residence. This is possible if doing so would be an undue hardship.

Comment: @o.m. There will be no embassy or consulate of your place of residence within your country of residence. I think you mean to say "...you should apply from your country of residence, at the embassy or consulate of your _destination country_..."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, I *think* I meant the case with several consulates and embassies in one country. No "visa shopping" within the country, either. Hence *country of residence* and *place of residence*.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply for a Schengen visa while you are a temporary resident in USA.

EDIT 1: [Schengen VISA](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/apply-from-united-states/)
has details regarding who and how can one apply for a schengen visa while residing in the US.
Note:  [Schengen VISA](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/) is a third party non official website. In my 4 years of living in Schengen area I have found it useful and accurate for all my travels. But of course it is recommended to contact the nearest embassy for 100% accuracy :)

EDIT 2: Personal experience in applying for schengen visa from USA while being a temporary resident in USA.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/129438)

Comment: It does answer the question asked.

Comment: Welcome to TSE, but please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. It is not enough to make a statement; answers on Stack Exchange are expected to be *definitive*. Your original answer provided no references or evidence, or even a statement of personal experience. Your edit merely adds a link to a third party non-official website with no indication as to why it should be trusted. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance on writing strong answers.

Comment: have edited the answer ;)